# Is there any way to run the python script continuously on reboot

Tags: python-3.x

Actually I am doing/want to do in the single python script:
1. Using Python I am writing some data to the Disk
2. Doing Reboot
3. Verifying the data
4. Other steps

Here after steps2, I want script should run after reboot on step 3 using the same script.
I'm fine if need to run the script manually again but when I run it should directly goto Step3.

Comment: If you run a script through a command-line by hand, why not consider specifying a special argument that directs the program to step 3?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, But I don't want to provide any argument while executing the python script

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve this is to have a state file that you write to after each step. When you start up the script, you can read from the file and then proceed to the desired state.

Comment: Hey arewm, can you please explain me this with example. Might be it will resolve my problem.

Comment: DuckPuncher beat me to the punch. I would put load_state() inside a try block, catching `FileNotFoundError` just in case something happens to the state file (and to handle the first time the script is run).

Answer (score 1):

Define the default state

```
DEFAULT_STATE = 'STEP1 START'
```

Save the state information to a file.

```
def write_state(state):
    with open('state.txt', 'w') as file_handle:
        file_handle.write(state)
write_state('STEP1 COMPLETE')
```

Then just load the state file and check to see what to do:

```
def load_state():
    try:
        with open('state.txt', 'r') as file_handle:
            for line in file_handle:
                line = line.strip()
                if line != '':
                    return line
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return DEFAULT_STATE

if load_state() == 'STEP1 COMPLETE':
    launch_step_2()
    write_state('STEP2 COMPLETE')
elif load_state() == 'STEP2 COMPLETE'):
    launch_step_3()
    write_state('STEP3 COMPLETE')
```

Just write some functions to handle each state, then call the functions and update the state file.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a dirty solution, but this is what you can do:
Before any steps:

```
import os.path
if os.path.isfile("step.txt"): # check if this file exists
    step3()
else:
    step1()
```

The function calls `step1` and `step3` represent your code parts.
During step 1:

```
f = open("step.txt", "w")
f.close()
```

With this action you will create a blank text file `step.txt` in the directory of your source code, so the `isfile()` method will return `True` because the file exists.

After all steps:

```
import os
os.remove("step.txt") # clean up
```